# If there's no NTP daemon in system, how should ntpd be called in order to query the system time offset, without setting the time?

Tags: ntp

How should I call ntpd if I only want to query the NTP, but I **do not** want to update the system time (as in "ntpdate -q")?
We do not have an NTP daemon in our proprietary system.

Thanks, Mechi

Answer (score 1):

You already answered yourself. `ntpdate -q` is used to query time sources. `ntpd` is not used for that.

Comment: Or since we have 2022 and ntpd is outdated for so long on any system since 18.04 you most likely run on systemd-timesyncd which you can query with `timedatectl` or if you wanted a server (or even just more advanced syncing) you should use chrony which you would check with `chronyc tracking`